# to_timestamp() passing the json data which is int and has unix timestamp not working in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, timestamp

```
info{
...
created_at:'1667801192'
}
```

select to_timestamp(info->'created_at') from booking;

info column has unix timestamp
expecting the whole column to convert as date

Comment: That is invalid JSON to begin with.

Comment: invalid in the sense can u elaborate

Comment: Invalid in the sense of [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) that defines JSON.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a typed language; every expression has a data type. The type of `info->'created_at'` is `json` or `jsonb` (depending on the type of `info`), and there is no function `to_timestamp` that accepts these data types as input. You will have to perform a type cast:

```
to_timestamp(CAST (info ->> 'created_at' AS double precision))
```